# Convert columns into rows respectively in SQL

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, rows

I really have been looking hard for an answer and still can't find one. Please help!

I have a workbook in excel that I would like to manipulate in Access using VBA or SQL.

The current problem I am facing is I have a spreadsheet where each row is a based on one invoice (2500 rows). Each row consists of  "Invoice Number" "PO Number" "Invoice Date" "Invoice Total". We can call that Invoice Data

Then in that row there are cells based on Line Item information, "Item Number" "Item Cost" "Item Quantity". Line Item Data

And the Line Item Data repeats until each line item from the invoices covered (i.e. if 70 line items, there would be 70 different line item data and a bunchhhhh of columns)

I need a way to make it so each row is based on the Line Item information, instead of the invoice information, while each row still keeps the items respective invoice info ( "Invoice Number" "PO Number" "Invoice Date" "Invoice Total").

Also the code needs to be simple enough that I don't need to tell it to copy line 1 item data then line 2 item data, etc until line item 70 data. (Maybe it can understand every 3 columns is a new item and the row it is on has its invoice info that it will take). It also can't stop when there are blank columns on row 1 because there could be 50 items in row 30. (invoice 1 had 3 line items, invoice 30 had 50 line items)

I will continue to look to find an answer and if I do find one I will post it here.. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I cannot see an easy way to do this unless every item detail set also contains an invoice number, and you indicate that it does not. If the transfer is once off, it would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub UnPivot()

Const INV_COLS As Integer = 4   'how many columns in the invoice info
Const ITEM_COLS As Integer = 3  'columns in each set of line item info

Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim rOut As Long, col As Long


    Set shtIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

    Set c = shtIn.Range("A2") 'first cell in invoice info
    rOut = 2                  'start row on output sheet

    'while the invoice cell is non-blank...
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        col = INV_COLS + 1   'column for first line item
        'while there's info in the line item cell 
        Do While Application.CountA(shtIn.Cells(c.Row, col).Resize(1, ITEM_COLS)) > 0

            'copy the invoice info (four cells)
            c.Resize(1, INV_COLS).Copy shtOut.Cells(rOut, 1)

            'copy the line item info (3 cells)
            shtIn.Cells(c.Row, col).Resize(1, ITEM_COLS).Copy _
                             shtOut.Cells(rOut, INV_COLS + 1)

            rOut = rOut + 1           'next output row
            col = col + ITEM_COLS     'move over to next line item
        Loop
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'move down one cell on input sheet
    Loop

    shtOut.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting run time error 9 subscript out of range, thanks again

Comment: On which line?  Do you have sheets called "Data" and "Output" in the Excel workbook containing the macro?

Comment: That was the problem, but now it is only giving me the output of the last few rows. I changed the amount of invoice columns and item columns, where the 4 and 3 were. I don't imagine I need to change it any where else, am I wrong?

Comment: When I tested it was with a dataset with four columns of invoice data starting at A2, and varying amounts of line item data starting in column E.  If you want to send me your workbook I will take a look.  Tim j williams at gmail dot com (no spaces)

Comment: Would you like to update the answer so others can use and I can rate?

Comment: is there a SQL for this? My excel keeps crashing due to large amounts of data.

Comment: How much data do you have? If speed is a problem then you can turn off screenupdating and set calculation to manual before doing the transformation (don't forget to set calculation back to automatic).

Comment: Initially there are 2800 rows, after the conversion it will turn into about 10,000

Comment: Should be absolutely no problem with that amount of data.  What exactly happens when it "crashes" ?

Comment: I did use  the screenupdate trick, and it worked very well!. I still would like to know if there is a way to convert an excel vba to access vba. I would think all I would have to change are the names of the inputs and outputs but I have no idea what the new names would be. Do you know how?